# Getting a concurrent Chinese Visa for new passport

Tags: visas, china

I have a business trip to China that is urgent, and my old passport expired. I sent it in to be renewed but it had my old Chinese Visa in it. I was able to get an appointment to go physically to the office to get a new passport tomorrow, but I still haven't received my old, expired passport with the unexpired visa in it to go to China. Is it possible to quickly get a new visa for the new passport that I will receive tomorrow, since I do not know when or if I could receive the old one back?
Thanks, I could not really find clear information on having a concurrent visa for China, and I would appreciate if you could provide a source on anything.

Comment: IIRC, you are required to submit a scan of all Chinese visas you've ever held

Comment: You will probably need to contact your local Chinese representation to get a really solid answer.

Answer (score 2):

In order to apply for a new visa, you need to provide records for 5 years of travel, and the last Chinese visa you've held: with a new passport it means supplying copies of the previous passport: ID page, and last visa.

So without your old passport – and that's assuming they would allow you to apply for a visa while you have a valid one – you won't be able to pass the first screening, where they check that you have all the docs required.

You'll have to wait for your old passport.